# How to detect if the last character in string is not a letter?

Tags: java, regex

How can I detect in Java if the last character in string is not a letter with regex  ?

```
^.*?[^A-Za-z]$
```

Comment: Does your current regex not work? Looks like it would to me.

Comment: Your regex should work. What is the issue?

Comment: The difference between "matches string with non-letter final character" vs "doesn't match string with letter final character" is how an empty string would match. So, depending on what you want try `str.matches(".*\\P{L}")` or `! str.matches(".*\\p{L}")`.

Comment: Try this condition in if statement !str.substring(str.length()-1).matches("[a-zA-Z]")

Answer (score 3):

I know it's not directly answering the question as it doesn't use a regex, but in this instance would it not be clearer to do something like this?

```
Character.isLetter(s.charAt(s.length()-1))
```

Where `s` is your String.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression should work. However a simpler version `str.matches(".*[^A-Za-z]"` will work too